# Fix <thead> on scrolling while preserving DOM in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I am working on a web page which displays a table which a lot of rows. User should be able to scroll the table, with `<thead>` fixed on the top of the table.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column A</th>
      <th>Column B</th>
      <!--Many other columns-->
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <!--Many tr and tds-->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

It doesn't matter if CSS or JavaScript (or even jQuery) is required, but they should **work in IE7**.

I've tried a lot of plugins, however most of them modifies the DOM by seperating `<thead>` and `<tbody>` and cloning another set of `<div>` wrappers.
I need to **preserve the DOM structure** since I have other plugins and scripts that relies on the DOM structure. (It's ok to add `<div>` wrappers outside the `<table>`)

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have to provide individual `position` attributes to your table structure.

Since you have not provided any code, I would suggest apply the following css to your code.

```
table {
  position: relative
}

thead {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 60px; // modify height accordingly
}

tbody {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px; // height of thead
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 120px; // height after which you want the scroll
}
```

And specifically for IE7 you need to add an expression,

```
thead tr {
   position: relative;
   top: expression(this.offsetParent.scrollTop);
}
```